# sqlx postgres scan method fail

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to perform a postgres query that contains a custom geoPoint type but get a Unexpected EOF error.  Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

```
type Account struct {
    Id             uint   `json:"id" db:"id"`
    RegistrationId string `json:"registration_id" db:"registration_id"`
    PhoneNumber    string `json:"phone_number" db:"phone_number"`
    AuthToken      string `json:"auth_token" db:"auth_token"`
    // Role           string `json:"-" db:"role"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"-" db:"created_at"`
    ActivatedAt time.Time `json:"-" db:"activated_at"`

    Location GeoPoint `json:"location" db:"location"`
}

// THE FAILING FUNCTION
func FindAccountByToken(db *sqlx.DB, token string) (Account, error) {
    var account Account
    log.Println("FindAcountByToken", token)
    err := db.Get(&account, "select * from accounts where auth_token = $1", token)
    return account, err
}

type GeoPoint struct {
    Latitude  float64 `json:"latitude" db:"latitude"`
    Longitude float64 `json:"longitude" db:"longitude"`
}

// String value
func (g *GeoPoint) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("(%v, %v)", g.Latitude, g.Longitude)
}

// Value of the geoPoint to be stored in the db based on the .String() method
func (g GeoPoint) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return g.String(), nil
}

// Scan converts the db []byte array value to the geoPoint value
func (g *GeoPoint) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    var source []byte
    var gp GeoPoint

    switch src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        source = src.([]byte)
    default:
        return errors.New("Unable to perform geopoint conversion")
    }

    log.Println("bytes -> ", source)

    reader := bytes.NewReader(source)
    if err := binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &gp); err != nil {
        log.Println("BinaryRead Error", err)
        return err
    }

    *g = gp

    return nil
}
```

Comment: How are you writing your geopoints to the database?  Are you using `binary.Write`?  Hard to tell what's going on without this.  The code of `GeoPoint.Value()` suggests that you're using some kind of arbitrary human-friendly string representation.  If that's the case, then `binary.Read` won't be an appropriate way to deserialize that representation.

Comment: That makes sense and after just casting the []byte array to a string it works.   This is what happens when you blindly follow someone else's example.  If you want to add your comment as an answer that would be awesome.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Uh... please add test cases.  If all you've done is add some arbitrary casts from bytes to strings, you've made a huge conceptual mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The GeoPoint implementation of `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces looks questionable.  They should be symmetric, but in one case, it represents the GeoPoint as a arbitrary-variable-length string of the form:

```
"(<latitude>, <longitude>)"
```

but in the other direction, expects a representation of exactly 16 bytes (two 64-bit floats in big-endian byte order).  This does not seem compatible.

Have you tested that the output value of `Value()` can be fed back into `Scan()` to get the same value?  Essentially, you should be able to do:

```
p1 := GeoPoint{3.1415926, 2.71828}
bs, _ := p1.Value()
p2 := GeoPoint{}
p2.Scan(bs)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p2)
```

and see the same value in `p2` as in `p1`.

For example, something like:

```
// Value of the geoPoint to be stored in the db
func (g *GeoPoint) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, g)
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}

// Scan converts the db []byte array value to the geoPoint value
func (g *GeoPoint) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    var source []byte
    switch src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        source = src.([]byte)
    default:
        return errors.New("Unable to perform geopoint conversion")
    }
    reader := bytes.NewReader(source)
    return binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, g)
}
```

should satisfy this property.  `Scan()` and `Value()` have to be conceptually consistent: otherwise, they wouldn't be useful.

Comment: You are right that the Valuer and Scanner were incompatible.  However from the postgres[1] docs it accepts (x, y) and the format for points, so I don't think I want to save the whole GeoPoint struct, but rather just the (x, y) coords. When using this approach the Scan method seems a little dirty since it has to parse out the lat, lng values from a "(lat,lng)" string, but it does work.

When trying to implement what you suggested point values of (0,0) were always saved.

1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-geometric.html

Comment: Sure, yes.  That's related to your database schema.  If the type of `accounts.location` is of postgres type `point`, then yes, what you're doing sounds reasonable.  Without the schema in hand, all I could say was that `Value` and `Scan` needed to match.  If the underlying type in the database were  a binary data type, like `bytea`, that'd be a factor.